# Present perfect with definite time

Tags: usage, present-perfect, time-words

Take a look at [this](http://www.srfa.ro/rrfa/pdf/RJAP-VI-2-Cernea-pp-92-104.pdf) philosophy paper. Here is the first sentence of it:

> One of the main themes that **have concerned** philosophers of language **in
>   the twentieth century** **has been** the semantics of proper names.

How can the present perfects be used here with a definite time? Please, keep in mind that the paper came out in 2012, which is in the 21st century (duh!).

Comment: Note that this paper has many errors of idiom and grammar; its author is not a native speaker of English.

Comment: @user3169 Once the twentieth century is over, the present perfect is no longer grammatically correct. Since the paper was written in 2012, the sentence was never grammatically correct.

Comment: Sounds like a person that's still writing 1999 on their checks.

Answer (score 1):

If it were still the twentieth century when the paper was written or published  then the use of the date would be fine. But since the twentieth century has passed, it is technically not correct.  Just as *Many papers have appeared yesterday* is technically incorrect.  Once is it no longer currently the mentioned time, the usage of the present perfect is technically incorrect. I say technically, because this is the traditional view, yet one sees this usage more often these days. Therefore  also, if the paper had said 2012 it would be correct.

*Have you seen Bob today?* is correct only when it is still today.

*Have you seen Bob yesterday?* is incorrect.

*Have you seen Bob this week?* is fine as long as it is still this week.

*Have you seen Bob this morning?* is good until it stops being this morning.

Comment: I am just curious: are you a native speaker?

Comment: I'm a native speaker of American English.

Comment: Does the sentence sound natural to you?

Comment: What does my answer say? The sentence only sounds natural if it were still the twentieth century. Perhaps the author is still living in the twentieth century?

Comment: My question was addressed to _you_ in particular. Grammar textbooks (as many textbooks on any other subject) tend to overgeneralize things, hence the "technically, the usage is incorrect". The sentence either sounds natural to a native speaker, or it doesn't.

Comment: Yet what sounds natural to an individual speaker may not represent standard grammar. That speaker's grammar may not be standard. Second, even if something does not sound natural, it may not be *incorrect* if it involves a usage that is *changing* and it sounds natural to some and unnatural to others. Hence *I have read a book yesterday* may sound natural to some if this usage is changing. That is why I said technically incorrect, as I have seen more and more  usages of this sort in major native  English publications. This may indicate a *change* in usage. Language use is not static.

Comment: Another example: *I have read yesterday that gas prices are down* is correct **if** the speaker is using *yesterday* to mean *recently*. However, not all native speakers may agree with me on this.

Comment: Isn't it always "this week"?  :-)  I would not use pres.perf. with "yesterday".

Comment: The "rule" in formal use is that the present perfect may not be employed with a temporal expression which does not *include* the present; but the rule is frequently violated in speech, where constituents are composed paratactically rather than syntactically; and the colloquialization of formal English over the past century has taken a good deal of glare off the error.

Comment: @StoneyB you lost me after the first semicolon.